# Turn on Track Changes in MS Word 2010 after changes already made

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I made changes to a Word .docx file but forgot to have "Track Changes" turned on. So to rectify this, I tried to `Undo` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>) all the changes, turn `Track Changes` on, then `Redo` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>) all the changes. Unfortunately, this didn't work: the changes were not marked. Is there any other way that I can backtrack and "capture" all my changes so my reviewer can easily see what changes I made?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found at least one solution to my problem. I used `Compare` to compare the original version with the revised version. The resulting comparison window displayed all changes as Tracked Changes. So I saved that comparison document as `mydoc_rev1`. When I open up `mydoc_rev1` and turned on Final:Show Markup, the changes were marked appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem wherein I edited half of a document while tracking changes, then opened it up again later, turned off track changes (for some reason) and edited the rest.

To solve it, I saved the document under a new file name, then clicked "compare" - "combine". I selected the two documents, and the resulting file showed all of my changes as tracked changes. Bingo.